# How do i implement mofo, dla, dl and fifo buffer management techniques on prophet router?

Tags: buffer, fifo, dtn, one-simulator

I am currently trying to evaluate the performance of ProPHET router using various buffer management technique such as MOFO, FIFO,DLA, and DL. I have written all the codes for each of the techniques and made them an individual classes and the saved them in a new folder I created(BufferManagement). I ran the simulation several times, but the classes I created seemed not to be having any effect on the performance of the said protocol. I rewrote all the codes and merged it into the Active router class. But still there was no any effect. Please kindly help me with some useful information as to where should the codes for buffer management techniques be placed and how it should be implemented on any router (or ProPHET router to be precise)?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in the title

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simulator is not using your new classes. You should store your new router module class files in the same folder as the other router modules and configure the simulator to use them with something like `Group.router = YourRoutingModuleClassName` in the settings.